# Getting a QDoubleDoubleSpinBox to display the (converted) value of a QSlider and still use setTracking(False)

Tags: python, qt, pyside, qspinbox, qslider

I'm creating a ui for an animation tool I've written. The ui consists of a QDoubleSpinBox and a QSlider. I have connected the QSlider to the QDoubleSpinBox with functions to convert their values. I would like to keep the spinbox updating with the valueChange of the slider. I would also like the spinbox's editingFinished() to update the position of the slider handle. I have this connection working.

There are two modes to the tool; "interactive" and "non-interactive". Interactive calls my animation tool's main function *as the slider is moved*, with the spinbox's/slider's value as the parameter. Non-interactive mode is meant to call my tool's function only when the slider is released. It looked like setTracking() on the slider was the answer, but of course it breaks the spinbox's behaviour of always showing the value of the slider.

Is there a way to keep the spinbox connected to the slider's value and still use setTracking(False) on the slider too? Is there another way to achieve the behaviour I'm looking for? I'm using Python and Pyside.

```
# jumping to relevant code

self.spinbox = QtGui.QDoubleSpinBox()
self.spinbox.setRange(0.0, 1.0)
self.spinbox.setDecimals(3)

self.sld = QtGui.QSlider()
self.sld.setRange(0, 1000)

self.sld.valueChanged[int].connect(self.update_spinbox)
self.spinbox.editingFinished.connect(self.update_slider_position)

def update_spinbox(self, value):
    self.spinbox.setValue(float(value)/1000)

def update_slider_position(self):
    self.sld.setSliderPosition(self.spinbox.value()*1000)
```

A menu in the ui toggles the setTracking() of the slider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may not be as elegant and simple as you want, but it should be the behavior you are after.

```
from PySide import QtGui

class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(Window, self).__init__(parent)

        self.updateFromSpinbox = False # Used so it slider doesn't run function twice
        self.spinbox = QtGui.QDoubleSpinBox()
        self.spinbox.setRange(0.0, 1.0)
        self.spinbox.setDecimals(3)
        self.spinbox.setSingleStep(0.1)

        self.sld = QtGui.QSlider()
        self.sld.setRange(0, 1000)

        self.checkButton = QtGui.QPushButton('Set interactive mode')
        self.checkButton.setCheckable(True)

        self.sld.valueChanged[int].connect(self.update_spinbox)
        self.sld.sliderReleased.connect(self.slider_released)
        self.spinbox.editingFinished.connect(self.update_slider_position)

        mainLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.spinbox)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.sld)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.checkButton)
        self.setLayout(mainLayout)

        self.resize(200, 200)
        self.show()

    # Runs when interactive mode is disabled
    def slider_released(self):
        if not self.checkButton.isChecked():
            self.myFunction()

    def update_spinbox(self, value):
        if not self.updateFromSpinbox:
            self.spinbox.setValue(float(value)/1000)
            if self.checkButton.isChecked():
                self.myFunction()

    def update_slider_position(self):
        self.updateFromSpinbox = True
        self.sld.setSliderPosition(self.spinbox.value()*1000)
        self.updateFromSpinbox = False
        self.myFunction()

    # Main function to run when value updates
    def myFunction(self):
        print self.sld.value()

win = Window()
```

When you check the button to go in interactive mode, `myFunction()` will be called when the slider is moving and when the spinbox is done editing. If it's checked off to go out of interactive mode, `myFunction()` will only be called when the slider is released and the spinbox is done editing.